# Determine if the subgroup $\{(1),(15)(23),(12)(35),(13)(25)\}$ of $S_5$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Determine if the subgroup $\{(1),(15)(23),(12)(35),(13)(25)\}$ of $S_5$ is cyclic.

What kind of methods I have in order to check wheter some group is cyclic? The identity here is $(1)$, but this group is not generated by $(15)(23)$ since it has order $2$. So if I just look at the orders of each element and find one that generates the group and has order $3$ that's the generator and the group will be cyclic? This method doesn't seem to generalize quite well if I would have larger groups.

Comment: For a subgroup of order $4$ to be cyclic, there must be an element of order $4$. So what is the order of the elements you have? Of course not $4$, so the group is $C_2\times C_2$ and not $C_4$.

Comment: Isn't it that there must be an element of order $n-1$? Which in this case would be $3$.

Comment: Yes, to show that a group is cyclic, most of the time, you would need to find an element that generates the whole group. In other words, find an element of order the same as the order of the group. Sometimes you can make the job easier by looking at a selective element, e.g. subgroup/quotient of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a group of order $n$ to be cyclic, it must have an element of order $n$ (it being a generator). This is necessary and sufficient for finite groups, but not for infinite groups; consider $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$, which is not cyclic yet has an element of infinite order.

Comment: This same applies to groups with infinite order? Say for example $\{\frac{1}{2^n} \mid n \in \Bbb Z\} = \langle \frac{1}{2}\rangle$?

Comment: It is a necessary, not a sufficient, condition, @Zwertp. For a counterexample, $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ has an element of infinite order but is not cyclic.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I would like to thank @user1729 for the suggestions in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59554885#59554885).